# What's the difference between Backbone.history.navigate and this.router.navigate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

What is the difference between `Backbone.history.navigate` and `this.router.navigate`?

Why would sometimes the former work while later won't?

Comment: `Backbone.history.navigate` seems to be undocumented? Maybe you're doing something wrong? Can you share [mcve] demonstrating this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Backbone source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/09cb8871d81b6f627c1edef46de97d7c2e8e2078/backbone.js#L1693-L1697), you'll see that `Router.prototype.navigate` is simply a proxy to `Backbone.history.navigate` which you can call anywhere without the need for a router instance.

> ```
> // Simple proxy to `Backbone.history` to save a fragment into the history.
> navigate: function(fragment, options) {
>   Backbone.history.navigate(fragment, options);
>   return this;
> },
> ```

Routing is handled in a [*global*, namespaced in Backbone, `History` instance](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/09cb8871d81b6f627c1edef46de97d7c2e8e2078/backbone.js#L2041-L2042).

This is meant to let developer create their own `History` class and then to overwrite the `Backbone.history` property to globally change the routing behaviour.

The `History` class isn't documented much, but it's [well commented in the source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/09cb8871d81b6f627c1edef46de97d7c2e8e2078/backbone.js#L1737-L2039).

Also, having a proxy to `navigate` in the `Router` class makes it easy to hook our own behaviour in the router directly.

---

As to why sometimes it doesn't work is probably because you're trying to do `this.router.navigate` in a class where `this.router` doesn't exist.

Comment: in initialize function I set `this.router = window.appRouter;` while `window.appRouter = new window.AppRouter();`   is already set.

Comment: @Rastee I'm answering what is possible to answer, like [T J said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883816/whats-the-difference-between-backbone-history-navigate-and-this-router-navigate/43895315?noredirect=1#comment74810158_43883816), without a [mcve] we can't see why it does not work _sometimes_ for you.